# How to find a file when it's ext unknown and get his ext in PHP?

Tags: php, image, file, if-statement, web

How can I find a file when it's ext unknown and get his ext in PHP?

I wrote this code but its not working (the if returns false)...
Thanks.

```
$pos_ext = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'tif', 'svg', 'bmp');



            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
            {   


            for ($i = 0 ; $i <= 6 ; ++$i)
            {
                $file_name = "/" . $row['ID'] . "/headerpic." . $pos_ext[$i];
                if (file_exists($file_name)) 
                {
                    $ext = $pos_ext[$i];
                }


            }
```

Comment: why aren't you storing the extension (or better yet, the full filename) in the database? What happens if you have `foo.jpg` and `foo.bmp` in that directory? You'd never be able to tell which file goes with which db record.

Comment: Why didn't you try printing $file_name and see what is in it? You'll find the problem quick enough...

Comment: The [man page of file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) mentions something about safe mode. Would it be the cause ?

Comment: the problam is in the if statmnt. I did try to print the problam is not there. there is one image in eche dir.

Comment: How about `image.*` or `glob("dir/image.{jpg,bmp,png}", GLOB_BRACE)`? And why not utilize the webservers content negotiation instead?